Failed to initialize virtual Python environment
enter image description here
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and VisualGDB for embedded system development and I face one error when install ESP-IDF on Visual Sutido 2022.
Run "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\VisualGDB\Python-3.8.10\python.exe c:\SysGCC\esp32\esp-idf/v5.2\tools\idf_tools.py install-python-env" in directory "" on local computer
--------------------------
WARNING: Is it not possible to determine the IDF version: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Espressif\\components\\esp_common\\include\\esp_idf_version.h'
ERROR: IDF version cannot be determined
--------------------------
Command exited with code 1

I want any expert can help me correct this error.
